# How to pass animation value to a child widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a widget that defines an animation. This animation progresses from 0.0 to 1.0. This widget also has a child widget, whose opacity I'd like to control in sync with the animation progress. However, I don't see how I can have the child widget's state "track" the state of the parent's animation progress. Whatever I give from the parent to the child ends up being `final` and, thus, immutable.

I tried passing the Animation directly, but then the app crashes with error "The getter `value` was called on null".

Edit: with code. My problem is that the MenuItem class can't be made aware of the states of the `Animation` values.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MenuItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function() onPressed;
  final String tooltip;
  final String helper;
  final IconData icon;

  MenuItem({this.onPressed, this.tooltip, this.helper, this.icon});

  @override
  _MenuItemState createState() => _MenuItemState();
}

class _MenuItemState extends State<MenuItem> {
  bool isOpened = true;
  double _elevateButtonValue = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          AnimatedOpacity(
            opacity: isOpened ? 1.0 : 0.0,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            child: new Container(
              child: Text(widget.helper),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration (
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(8.0)),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                    offset: Offset(0.0, 6.0),
                    blurRadius: 16.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 12.0),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            tooltip: widget.tooltip,
            child: Icon(widget.icon),
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            elevation: _elevateButtonValue,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MenuFabs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MenuFabsState createState() => _MenuFabsState();
}

class _MenuFabsState extends State<MenuFabs>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isOpened = false;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<Color> _buttonColor;
  Animation<double> _animateIcon;
  Animation<double> _translateButton;
  Animation<double> _elevateButton;
  Curve _curve = Curves.easeOut;
  double _fabHeight = 56.0;

  @override
  initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });
    _animateIcon =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController);
    _buttonColor = ColorTween(
      begin: Colors.deepOrange,
      end: Colors.black45,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.00,
        1.00,
        curve: Curves.linear,
      ),
    ));
    _translateButton = Tween<double>(
      begin: _fabHeight,
      end: -14.0,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.0,
        0.75,
        curve: _curve,
      ),
    ));
    _elevateButton = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0.0,
      end: 6.0,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.25,
        1.0,
        curve: _curve,
      ),
    ));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  animate() {
    if (!isOpened) {
      _animationController.forward();
    } else {
      _animationController.reverse();
    }
    isOpened = !isOpened;
  }

  Widget goal() {
    return Container(
      child: new MenuItem(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Geolocate',
        helper: 'Geolocate',
        icon: Icons.radio_button_checked,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget invite() {
    return Container(
      child: new MenuItem(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Invite friends',
        helper: 'Invite friends',
        icon: Icons.person_add,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget toggle() {
    return Container(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: _buttonColor.value,
        onPressed: animate,
        tooltip: 'Toggle',
        child: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
          progress: _animateIcon,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value * 2.0,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: goal(),
        ),
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: invite(),
        ),
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            168.0,
            0.0,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: toggle(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @JordanDavies I've added the code, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` to the child Widget made the error go away!